# Can I use multiple 'await' in an async function's try/catch block?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

i.e.

```
async asyncfunction(){
  try{
    await method1();
    await method2();
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Given method1() and method2() are asynchronous functions. Should there be a try/catch block for each await method? Is there an even cleaner way to write this? I'm trying to avoid '.then' and '.catch' chaining.

Comment: It depends on whether you need the `catch` to do something different depending on which function caused the error. A single try/catch is often fine

Comment: Have you tried the following? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I found this article helpful. It deals, amongst other aspects, with the implications of this kind of usage.
https://dev.to/maxart2501/gotchas-about-asyncawait-and-promises-9di

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using one try/catch block containing multiple `await` operations is fine when waiting for promises created on the right hand side of the `await` unary operator:

The `await` operator stores its parent `async` functions' execution context and returns to the event loop. Execution of the `await` operator resumes when it is called back with the settled state and value of its operand.

Upon resumption, `await` restores the previously saved execution context and returns the operand promise's fulfilled value as the result of the `await` expression, or throws the rejection reason of a rejected operand.

The `try/catch` block invocation is part of the execution context both before and after being saved and restored. Hence multiple `await` operations do not disturb the behavior of an outer `try` block  they share. The `catch` block will be invoked with the rejection reason of any promise awaited in the `try` block that is rejected.

**Uncaught Rejection warning**

If code `await`s promises that were not created by the `await` operator's argument expression, and don't have a rejection handler, the promises won't have a rejection handler before the `await` operator applied to them is executed *at runtime*.

If the try/catch block is triggered before `await` adds a handler to such promises, and they reject, an uncaught rejection error occurs. Thanks to @EyolRoth for this caveat, Please see his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644993/5217142) for a case example.

Recommendation: consider carefully if you need to await a promise that was created earlier and doesn't have an error handler. Then examine

- how its creation could be moved to the `await`'s  operand expression, or
- synchronously add a rejection handler to it when first created, or
- [defeat it's uncaught promise detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59062117/5217142), which I previously posted in answer to [How to handle an unhandled promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59060508/5217142)

Comment: Throwing uncaughts on awaiting multiple *existing* promises is such an **unintuitive** behavior.

Comment: I wonder if there is an eslint rule to disallow parallel promises when an `await` is encountered.

Answer (score 13):

While @traktor [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50557863/114626) is correct, I want to add a very important caveat.

The following code snippet is unsafe:

```js
async function foo() {
  try {
    const p1 = method1();
    const p2 = method2();

    await p1;
    await p2;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

If both promises are rejected, the code will result in `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` in NodeJS, potentially killing the process if the option `--unhandled-rejections` is set to `throw` (which will become the default behavior from Node 15).

**Why is this happening?**

In the original code of the question, the async methods are invoked sequentially; i.e, if the first method fails (promise rejected), the second method is never invoked.

However, the code from the beginning of this answer invokes both of the async methods in parallel; i.e, the second method is invoked regardless if the first method succeeds or not.

In this scenario, only the `await` on the promise of the second method is conditioned on the success of the first method. Meaning, if the first method fails, the promise of the second method (which has already started) is never awaited, so if it fails too, it will result in an handled promise rejection.

**How to overcome this behavior?**

Assuming we wish to handle both rejections in the same way, we can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
try {
  const p1 = method1();
  const p2 = method2();
  
  await Promise.all([p1, p2]);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Only the first promise to be rejected will "trigger" the `catch` clause, while the second will be silently ignored without crashing the process.

Comment: Great information for the case of executing promised tasks in parallel!

Answer (score 0):

Using Async.js Library
Let's talk about working with the async.js library in order to avoid callback hell.

As per the official website of async.js : Async is a utility module which provides straight-forward, powerful functions for working with asynchronous JavaScript.

Async.js provides near about 70 functions in total. For now, we will discuss only two of them i.e, async.waterfall() and async.series().

async.waterfall()
This method is useful when you want to run some tasks one after the other and then pass the result from the previous task to the next task. It takes an array of functions "tasks" and a final "callback" function that is called after all functions in "tasks" array have completed or a "callback" is called with an error object.

[async.js library](https://dzone.com/articles/javascript-callback-functions-in-depth-guide-for-2)