# How to handle an unhandled promise rejection asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, async-await

I'm trying to wrap my head around this issue I'm facing concerning async/await and Promises. I managed to boil my issue down to the following code:

```
async function sleep(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function fetchMock(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(() => {
    throw 'error fetching result';
  });
}

async function main(): Promise<any> {
  const kickedOffRequest = fetchMock();
  await sleep(10);
  return kickedOffRequest;
}

main()
  .then(() => console.log('resolved promise!'))
  .catch(error => console.error('caught error!', error));
```

I receive the following warning:

```
(node:82245) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error fetching result
(node:82245) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:82245) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
caught error! error fetching result
(node:82245) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
```

You can observe the same issue [in this sandbox](https://repl.it/repls/PositiveBrokenPrinters). I noticed that commenting out the `await sleep(10)` fixes the issue, but I apparently know less about promises than I thought. Why does commenting that line out make my program work? I'm tempted to ask how to fix the `Promise rejection was handled asynchronously` error, but I hope that once I understand how `await sleep(10)` causes the error I get I will be able to fix this one on my own.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read/answer this question!

Comment: @Bergi - I don't see how the duplicate you marked actually provides a solution to this specific problem.  What the OP appears to want in `main()` is to return the promise from `fetchMock()` whether rejected or resolved, but not have it resolve or reject until at least 10ms have passed.  I don't see how to do that in your dup.  So, if `fetchMock()` resolves or reject immediately, then the promise returned from `main()` wouldn't resolve or reject for 10ms.  But, if the promise from `fetchMock()` took more than 10ms to resolve or reject, no further delay would be added to that resolve or reject.

Comment: @jfriend00 to me, it was unclear what behaviour the OP really wants, but the dupe is our canonical explaining why the current attempt doesn't work and why `Promise.all` should be used instead

Comment: Well, there's no obvious use of `Promise.all()` that creates the exact timing that `main()` shows.  [Canonical answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) work fine for canonical questions, not questions that raise a different variant for which a solution is not shown in the canonical answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's exactly what I want, thank you. In my "real" program I kick off a network request and then sleep for some time. I don't want to await my network request at this point, so `Promise.all` is not the thing I want here.

Comment: Do you want an answer that actually does what you described - including rejecting the returned promise rather than the work-around in the answer you've already accepted?  I figured out a way to do it, but it will take me a bit of time to make sure it works properly.

Comment: Sure, I would be very thankful! I honestly was not aware that I accepted a workaround, I just thought that that was the way to go to prevent the `Unhandled promise rejection`. If you found a way to reject the promise I'd be glad to see your solution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The detection of unhandled rejection in node.js is imperfect.  There are specific spots in the life cycle of a rejected promise where the engine checks to see if there's a handler and it does not always wait until the last possible moment so it can miss places that you add a handler.  In your specific case, you may need to attach a `.catch()` handler locally, then finish up the work you want to do, then rethrow the error.  This work-around will work for you while still maintaining the desired resolve/reject from `main()` (e.g. without changing the interface to main).

So, this isn't particularly super pretty, but it meets the spec we talked about in comments.

1. `main()` calls `fetchMock()`
2. If it resolves or rejects quickly (before some custom delay time), then it holds off on the resolve or the reject until at least that delay time has elapsed from when `fetchMock()` was originally called.
3. If `fetchMock()` takes longer than that custom delay time to resolve or reject, then no further delay is added.
4. The promise that `main()` returns then follows the promise that `fetchMock()` returned, either rejected or resolved with the same reason or value.

The key ingredient is that it captures the time right before calling `fetchMock()` and then when `fetchMock()` either resolves or rejects, it decides whether to delay any more time before passing the resolve/reject value/reason on through.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

function fetchMock() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        throw 'error fetching result';
        //resolve('this is our result');
    });
}


function handler(start, minWaitTime, isErr = false) {
    return async function(val) {
        let diff = minWaitTime - (Date.now() - start);
        if (diff > 0) {
            await sleep(diff);
        }
        if (isErr) {
            throw val;
        } else {
            return val;
        }
    }
}

function main() {
    let start = Date.now();
    const minWaitTime = 1000;
    return fetchMock().then(handler(start, minWaitTime), handler(start, minWaitTime, true));
}

main()
    .then(() => console.log('resolved promise!'))
    .catch(error => console.error('caught error!', error));
```

Note, also that `sleep()` and `fetchMock()` already directly return promises and don't use `await` so there is no requirement for them to be `async`.

Comment: @marcelHaupenthal - OK, here's a way to do it.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks for taking your time for me. I think this is the solution I was looking for. I'm going to have to read some more documentation about promises, but this helps me alot! Have a great day.

Answer (score 14):

**How to defeat uncaught promise rejections**

The original concept of promises was that you could have a rejected promise sitting around for some time before attaching a catch handler to it. For example, Firefox used to warn of uncaught rejection errors only when a rejected promise with no rejection handler was garbage collected from memory.

A subsequent amendment to HTML specifications requireg that browsers throw "unhandled promise rejection" errors if a rejected promise has no rejection handlers added before code returns to the event loop.

(I think unhandled rejections can survive without error in the micro task queue for a tick or two, before control returns to the event loop proper, but haven't tested it lately.)

The ECMAScript specification added an abstract means of [notifying the host environment of an unhandled promise rejection](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-host-promise-rejection-tracker) without specifying what, if any, action should be taken.

On a case by case basis you can prevent the host being notified by adding a rejection handler that is never used. The reasoning is that adding a dummy rejection handler to a promise means that should it be rejected it has a rejection handler already - or if it was rejected the host is notified the promise now has a rejection handler - and you can call `then` and `catch` multiple times on the same promise.

Changing

```
async function fetchMock(){
  return new Promise(() => {
    throw 'error fetching result';
  });
}
```

to

```
async function fetchMock(){
  let promise = new Promise(() => {
    throw 'error fetching result';
  });
  promise.catch(()=>null); // unused rejection handler
  return promise;
}
```

should work around HTML5 host behavior in standard JavaScript engines, including V8, the JavaScript engine used in node and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `fetchMock` rejects *immediately*, and when a Promise rejects, *at the time that it rejects*, it must be chained with a `.catch` somewhere in order to prevent an Unhandled Promise Rejection.

With your `await sleep(10)`, the `kickedOffRequest` promise rejects while the `main` function is still waiting for `sleep` to resolve. When there's a rejection, the interpreter doesn't *look ahead* to see if the Promise may be caught in the future (for example, to see if the Promise gets returned or caught) - the Promise must be caught *now*.

When you remove the `await`, `kickedOffRequest` still becomes a rejected Promise, but it's returned from `main` *immediately*, so at the point that the Promise rejects, it can be seen and caught by the outer `.catch`, so there's no Unhandled Rejection warning.

---

It's good if a Promise rejection can be handled *right when* it rejects, but if that's not an option for you, you can put another `.catch` onto the end of the inner Promise. That way, the warning won't appear (because of the existence of `.catch`, even if that `.catch` didn't do anything meaningful) and you can *later* check to see if an error actually occurred or not:

```js
async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function fetchMock(){
  return new Promise(() => {
    throw 'error fetching result';
  });
}

async function main() {
  const kickedOffRequest = fetchMock()
    .then(resolved => ({ resolved }))
    .catch(rejected => ({ rejected }));
  await sleep(10);
  return kickedOffRequest;
}

main()
  .then(({ resolved, rejected }) => {
    if (resolved) {
      console.log('resolved promise!');
    } else {
      console.error('caught error!', rejected);
    }
  });
```

This is pretty similar to how `Promise.allSettled` works (though it's more intended for when there's an *array* of Promises that need to be parsed):

```js
async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function fetchMock(){
  return new Promise(() => {
    throw 'error fetching result';
  });
}

async function main() {
  const kickedOffRequestArr = Promise.allSettled([fetchMock()]);
  await sleep(10);
  return kickedOffRequestArr;
}

main()
  .then(([{ result, reason, value }]) => {
    if (result === 'fulfilled') {
      console.log('resolved promise!', value);
    } else {
      console.error('caught error!', reason);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! That clears things up. I'm not sure how I feel about returning a Promise that resolves to a "wrapper" around an error or an actual response. I liked just throwing the error in a nested function and making the user of `main` react to the error, but if I understood correctly, that's not really possible, is it?

Comment: Right. It's possible, but only barely - it's not a good idea due to the rejection warning, which will eventually become an error by Node (at which point it will be actually impossible).