# Calling DynamoDB query and then writing result to s3 bucket: How to simplify this code with async await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following lambda function that reads from a DynamoDB table then writes the result to a spreadsheet on the S3 bucket.

It works fine but I'd like to improve it using async await. Is this possible?

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
const excel = require('excel4node');
const workbook = new excel.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

const contactsTable = process.env.CONTACTS_TABLE;
const contactsBucket = process.env.CONTACTS_BUCKET;
const bucketRegion = process.env.REGION;

  module.exports.exportContactsByID = (event, _context, callback) => {
  const id = event.pathParameters.id;
  const params = {
    TableName: contactsTable,
    IndexName: "company_id-created_at-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "company_id = :v_ID",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":v_ID": id,
    },
    ProjectionExpression: "company_name, contact_name, age, phone, email, dsr_ratio, max_eligibility, created_at_local, selected_banks"
  };

return db.query(params).promise()
.then((res) => {
  const items = res.Items;
  if(res.Count === 0){
    return callback(null, response(200, `No records found for id ${id}`));
  }
  // Headers + Columns
  worksheet.cell(1, 1).string('Client').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 2).string('Name').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 3).string('Age').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 4).string('Email').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 5).string('Phone').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 6).string('DSR Ratio').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 7).string('Max Eligibility').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 8).string('Submission Date').style({font: {bold: true}});
  worksheet.cell(1, 9).string('Banks').style({font: {bold: true}});
  // Rows
  items.forEach((item, i) => {
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 1).string(item.company_name);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 2).string(item.contact_name);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 3).string(item.age);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 4).string(item.email);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 5).string(item.phone);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 6).string(item.dsr_ratio);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 7).string(item.max_eligibility);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 8).string(item.created_at_local);
    worksheet.cell(i + 2, 9).string(item.selected_banks);
  });
  return workbook.writeToBuffer().then(buffer => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: contactsBucket,
      Key: `contacts/${id}.xlsx`,
      Body: buffer,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }
    const fileURL = `https://${contactsBucket}.s3-${bucketRegion}.amazonaws.com/contacts/${id}.xlsx`;
    return S3.upload(params).promise().then(_data => {
      callback(null, response(200, fileURL));
});
  })
})
.catch((err) => callback(null, response(err.statusCode, err)));
};
```

The code above is the improved version from the original code I had [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513590/aws-lambda-nodejs-writing-to-s3-behaves-differently-on-local-and-sever/62513815#62513815). Thank you for reading.

Comment: where do `worksheet` and `workbook` come from? also it appears worksheet isn't being used anywhere.

Comment: My bad, I've updated the code. I'm using the package excel4node to write to the S3 spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557259/can-i-use-multiple-await-in-an-async-functions-try-catch-block), I simplified the code as the following - by having multiple `awaits`

```
  module.exports.exportContactsByID = async (event, _context) => {
  const id = event.pathParameters.id;
  const params = {
    TableName: contactsTable,
    IndexName: "company_id-created_at-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "company_id = :v_ID",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":v_ID": id,
    },
    ProjectionExpression: "company_name, contact_name, age, phone, email, dsr_ratio, max_eligibility, created_at_local, selected_banks"
  };

try {
    const res = await db.query(params).promise();
    if(res.Count === 0){
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,    
        headers: {    
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',    
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,    
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          status: `No records found for company id ${id}`,
        }),
      };  
      return response;
    }
    else {
    // Headers + Columns
    const items = res.Items;
    worksheet.cell(1, 1).string('Client').style({font: {bold: true}});
    worksheet.cell(1, 2).string('Name').style({font: {bold: true}});
    worksheet.cell(1, 3).string('Age').style({font: {bold: true}});
    worksheet.cell(1, 4).string('Email').style({font: {bold: true}});
    worksheet.cell(1, 5).string('Phone').style({font: {bold: true}});
    worksheet.cell(1, 6).string('DSR Ratio').style({font: {bold: true}});
    worksheet.cell(1, 7).string('Max Eligibility').style({font: {bold: true}});
    worksheet.cell(1, 8).string('Submission Date').style({font: {bold: true}});
    worksheet.cell(1, 9).string('Banks').style({font: {bold: true}});
    // Rows
    items.forEach((item, i) => {
      worksheet.cell(i + 2, 1).string(item.company_name);
      worksheet.cell(i + 2, 2).string(item.contact_name);
      worksheet.cell(i + 2, 3).string(item.age);
      worksheet.cell(i + 2, 4).string(item.email);
      worksheet.cell(i + 2, 5).string(item.phone);
      worksheet.cell(i + 2, 6).string(item.dsr_ratio);
      worksheet.cell(i + 2, 7).string(item.max_eligibility);
      worksheet.cell(i + 2, 8).string(item.created_at_local);
      worksheet.cell(i + 2, 9).string(item.selected_banks);
    });
    const buffer = await workbook.writeToBuffer();
    const params = {
            Bucket: contactsBucket,
            Key: `contacts/${id}.xlsx`,
            Body: buffer,
            ACL: 'public-read'
    }
    const fileURL = `https://${contactsBucket}.s3-${bucketRegion}.amazonaws.com/contacts/${id}.xlsx`;
    const s3 = await S3.upload(params).promise(); 
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,    
      headers: {    
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',    
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,    
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        fileURL: fileURL,
      }),
    };  
    return response;
  } 
}
catch (err){
  console.log(err);
  return err;
}
};
```

Comment: It looks very good. I would, however, remove the outer `try`...`catch` so the caller (the Lambda engine) handle the errors. Or, at least, rethrow the exception instead of returning it.

Comment: Thank you for the kind feedback. If I remove the try...catch statement, how would the caller handle the errors ya? Is there some example I can see? Apology for the noob question, I'm still finding my ways around Lambda.

Comment: The way it is currently written, you're swallowing exceptions. Just let them be, so the exception will reject the promise returned by your async function call. The Lambda runtime will catch it and handle accordingly. You can try it yourself: `module.exports.raiseException = async() => { throw new Error('magic?') }`.